# Получить публичный ключ из приватного bitcoin

Tags: c++, key, криптография, bitcoin, sha256

Правильно ли я понимаю, что получить адрес bitcoin кошелька из приватного ключа можно алгоритмом на картинке ниже:
[image: Получение публичного ключа из приватного]

И есть ли готовое решение для C++?

Comment: Есть подозрение, что поиски готового решения займут чуть больше, чем написание с нуля...

Comment: То, что у вас на рисунке - это преобразование публичного ключа в адрес.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно эта библиотека поможет вам в решение вашей задачи: 
https://github.com/libbtc/libbtc